# Triangle not showing on some devices

Tags: java, android, geometry, opengl-es-2.0

I have a game that is working well on many devices (Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7, ect.) but have some issues on others(Galaxy Note 10.1, Galaxy S2). It is written in Java, OpenGL ES 2.0, Android 2.2+

Some triangles are not displayed, as you can see on this picture :

[bug http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/3765/zxuv.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/3765/zxuv.png)

What could be causing this issue ? Does anyone had such issues ? I don't have these devices so I can't test...

Thanks.

Here's some code from the road rendering :

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
GLES20.glDepthMask(true);

GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

...

```
vertex_position_handle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vertex_position");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_position_handle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_position_handle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, vertex_buffer);
```

...

```
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 * line_cnt);
```

...

```
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normal_handle);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(texture_coordinate_handle);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertex_position_handle);
```

Comment: Do you have an SSCCE demonstrating the problem? That would be helpful.

Comment: I have added some code, the thing is my code works on many devices, but not all.

Comment: When I mean an SSCCE, I mean a complete code demonstrating the problem. Code extracts like this may lead knowledgeable people to spot the solution immediately, or maybe not (note: I don't know anything about OpenGL myself)

Comment: sorry but the code is huge and not open source, I hope someone experienced with opengl es 2 will see my problem :)

Comment: Even in this case, writing an SSCCE may help you pinpoint the problem more accurately, and also help other people answer ;) Remember that the first `S` stands for "Short"